# Files and Directories Dissappearing from Software Raid on Power Failure

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a home samba file "server" (a raspberry pi) with two hard drives in a software raid 1, which have proven less reliable than any of my non-raid disks.  I know there is a chance for data corruption when power is lost, but I have now lost two entire directories and a file I was working on due to power being lost (all separate occasions).  The power was cut and when I rebooted, the file was empty.  The other two times, the folders were just gone.  Why might this be happening?  Also, shouldn't a journaling file system prevent this?  Might there be a way to recover the data?

Comment: What filesystem are you using on top of the RAID?

Comment: The file system is ext4.

Answer (score 0):

RAID is not magic.  It's a technique for increasing uptime in the face of a hard-drive failure, and nothing more.  If you want to keep from losing data in the event of a power failure, get a UPS.

Journaling is not magic.  It's a technique for ensuring filesystem consistency in the face of an unexpected shutdown, and nothing more.  It does this by making certain actions "all or nothing": either an action (such as creating a file) will have taken place, or it won't have -- you'll never find your disk with an action halfway done (eg. a file with space allocated for it, but no directory entry).  It speeds up recovery in the event of a power failure, because the OS knows it doesn't need to go looking for the results of partly-completed actions.  If you want to keep from losing data in the event of a power failure, get a UPS.

In short, the problem you're running into is that you're using the wrong tools for the job.  If you want to keep from losing data in the event of a power failure, you need to keep power running to your computer until it can cleanly shut down.  This means you need a UPS.